# Zxing.Net.Mobile barcode app not accessing Lumia 650 camera

Tags: c#, camera, barcode, zxing, windows-10-mobile

I am currently using a Microsoft Lumia 650 with Windows 10 Mobile and I am having issues with implementing a Zxing.Net.Mobile barcode app. The issue is the camera does not appear to be used and I was wondering what could be the issue.

I have tested this same app on a developer version of windows 10 and it worked fine. I have the phone in developer mode as well as set the setting in the camera privacy settings to allow apps to use the camera.

The code that I am using is the same as the Sample Windows Phone Application listed at https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/tree/master/Samples/WindowsUniversal/Sample.WindowsUniversal.

If anyone has any experience with this or information on how to fix this issue, I would be greatly appreciative.

Thanks.

EDIT: The exact issue I am getting is that once you select an option to scan, the layout loads up but there is a white background where the cameras' visual should be. Also, the app does not show up in my "Choose apps that can use your camera" in the privacy/camera settings.

Comment: I can see <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" /> in the Package.appxmanifest in ZXing.Net example, did you check this capability in your manifest? It's under Capabilities -> Webcam

Comment: Awesome! That was it! Thank you so much!